# My winreg function is not being recognized

Tags: c++, registry, regedit

The error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'RegCreateKeyExW'
```

What I am including:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <winreg.h>
```

My code:

```
        HKEY hKey;
        LONG result = 0;
        char *path = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\IDConfigDB\\Hardware Profiles\\0001";

        if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, NULL,
                REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            printf("2. success \n");
        } else {
            printf("fail\n");
        }
```

I have tried everything but this error won't vanish, I would aprecciate if someone could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `TCHAR` version of `RegCreateKeyEx()`. It is clear from the error message that `RegCreateKeyEx()` is resolving to the Unicode version, `RegCreateKeyExW()` (because `UNICODE` is defined in your build config). That version takes in a wide `wchar_t` string as input, but you are passing in a narrow `char` string instead.

You can either:

1. use a `TCHAR` string, to match the `TCHAR` function your code is calling:

```cpp
const TCHAR* path = TEXT("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\IDConfigDB\\Hardware Profiles\\0001");
```

2. use a Unicode string, to match the Unicode function actually being called at runtime:

```cpp
const wchar_t *path = L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\IDConfigDB\\Hardware Profiles\\0001";
```

3. use the ANSI version of the function, `RegCreateKeyExA()`, to match your original string:

```cpp
if (RegCreateKeyExA(...) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks, this solved the error, but now it is not finding the key through that path, do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: @El_Sapo_Pepe did you verify with RegEdit that the key actually exists? Are you compiling your app for 32bit or 64bit, and does the key exist in the [32bit or 64bit area of the Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view)?

Comment: Do I need to run the program in admin mode in order to do this?

Comment: @El_Sapo_Pepe likely, as most of HKLM is generally restricted to read-only for non-admins, and you are open in the key for writing. `RegCreateKeyEx()` returns an [error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes) if it can't open/create the key, ie due to insufficient rights, but you are not printing out that error code in your `printf()`, eg: `LONG lRet = RegCreateKeyEx(...); if (lRet == ERROR_SUCCESS) { ... } else { printf("fail, error %d\n", lRet); }`

Comment: it's better to use powershell script for this